# enviar caracteres especiales(ñáé) por email con formulario PHP

Tags: php, html

Hola Programadores un saludo,
requiero de ayuda, tengo un formulario en php que envia datos por email todo funciona muy bien a excepción de que si alguien coloca algún carácter especial como ñ o tildes en las palabras el correo no se envía, adjunto el codigo.

intente agregando encode en el mensaje pero no me funciona alguna idea de como puedo solucionar el tema o que estoy haciendo mal

gracias por su ayuda.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {

?>


<?php

}else{

  $mensaje="Mensaje del formulario de contacto";

  $mensaje.= "\nNombre: ". $_POST['nombre'];

  $mensaje.= "\nEmail: ".$_POST['email'];

  $mensaje.= "\nCedula: ".$_POST['cedula'];

  $mensaje.= "\nTelefono: ". $_POST['telefono'];

  $mensaje.= "\nDireccion: ". $_POST['direccion'];

  $mensaje.= "\nCiudad: ". $_POST['cosa'];

  $mensaje.= "\nSede: ". $_POST['opt'];

  
  $destino= "correo@correo.com.co";


  $remitente = $_POST['email']; 

  $asunto ="Mensaje del formulario de contacto";
 /*  $asunto = "Mensaje enviado por: ".$_POST['nombre']; */

  mail($destino,$asunto,$mensaje, "FROM: $remitente");

?>
<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso lo puedes solucionar haciendo uso de `iconv()`, lo que hace es convierte un string a la codificación de caracteres indicada.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8'); //esta línea al inicio de tu archivo
$var= preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '',iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $var));
```

Por ejemplo:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$var = 'Árbol lápiz Élite Félix Índice mí Órbita natación Único algún Ñoño ñáé';
$var = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '',iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $var));
echo $var;
```

Eso te va a imprimir:

```
Arbol lapiz Elite Felix Indice mi Orbita natacion Unico algun Nono nae
```

Aplica lo mismo para cualquier tipo de cadena, con eso solucionas tu problema por completo.

Comment: Hola amigo funciona a la perfección, mi pregunta es si quiero que envié los caracteres como podría solucionar esto es decir que envié las ñ y las tildes? 
gracias

Comment: Te iba a poner aquí el código, pero es básicamente lo que respondió @aeportugal en la respuesta de abajo, todo lo que esta dentro del function es lo único que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien ya aceptaste otra respuesta como válida, pongo esta otra información de forma complementaria. Te aconsejo que construyas bien las cabeceras del correo (headers), de esta forma es un poco menos probable que los clientes de correo y firewalls te los detecten como spam.
Una función sencilla para enviar correo, formateado como HTML, puede ser como este ejemplo que personalmente uso en producción:

```
<?php
function enviar_correo($from, $name, $to, $cc, $subject, $message) {
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $name <$from>"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: $to" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: $cc" . "\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

$from = 'direccion_de_envio@dominio.com';
$name = 'Nombre remitente con Eñe';
$to = 'recipiente1@dominio1.com,recipiente2@dominio2.com';
$cc = '';
$subj = 'Correo de Prueba';
$msg = '<h3>Este es un mensaje de prueba</h3>'.PHP_EOL;
$msg .= '<p>Mensaje con tildes y ñ: á ü Ññ</p><br>'.PHP_EOL;

enviar_correo($from, $name, $to, $cc, $subj, $msg);
```

Si lo quieres como texto plano, puedes cambiar a `Content-type: text/plain` y eliminar el html del msg.

Si bien, la función `mail()` puede resolver para hacer pequeñas cosas, en proyectos importantes, o que ejecuten en otra plataforma distinta a Windows, es mejor utilizar otras librerías, como [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: muchas gracias lo probare.